# google calendar API recurring event by HOURLY

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I try to create (Events: insert) recurring events every 3 hours on google calendar API in C # (also on 'Try this API').

But I Have this message :

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid recurrence rule."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid recurrence rule."
 }
}
```

Here is the object (body request) I send to the google API :

```
{
  "description": "",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-06-16T15:55:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Paris"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-06-16T16:55:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Paris"
  },
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=5;UNTIL=20190617T170000Z"
  ]
}
```

Have I omitted an element or does google calendar API no longer handle recurrences on an hourly frequency (this is not what RFC 5545 seems to indicate https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3 .10)?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm an expert on RFC's.  The IEEE sponsors working group that create the RFC documents.  The working group consists usually from companies that are going to create or use the document.  Usually a preliminary version of the document is created and then companies go and develop the hardware/software to meet specification.  Then a certification and inter-compatibility is performed.  Often two companies software will not work under certain conditions.  So the RFC is modified so both companies software will meet the requirements instead of having one company change their software.

Comment: Google may not of implemented the option in the RFC to handle hourly while other companies versions of the RFC does allow hourly frequencies.

Comment: Thanks, So I do not understand the google documentation that says that the recurrence field includes the properties defined in RFC5535. https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#instances_and_exceptions
Why not say what's wrong with the RFC definition.

Comment: You have to contact Google to see if they implemented Hourly.  Even though the google API says they meet RFC-5535, it doesn't mean they implemented everything in RFC-5535.  I can't tell if RFC-5535 is wrong, the link you provided is wrong, or your code is wrong.

Comment: This is why I said I'm an expert on RFC.  I've see too many cases where vendors hardware/software doesn't completely meet the RFC documents.  You sometime have to read the RFC twenty times before you realize that a requirement is optional or there is more than one way to implement the requirement.  You almost have to be a Lawyer to be able to read a RFC.  Para 2 says : The key words "MUST", "MUST NOT", "REQUIRED", "SHALL", "SHALL NOT",
   "SHOULD", "SHOULD NOT", "RECOMMENDED", "MAY", and "OPTIONAL" in this
   document are to be interpreted as described in

Comment: I would look very carefully at the table on Page 44 of the RFC.

Comment: You put 10 Lawyers in a room you will get 10 different answers.